# How to choose option of select control in Cypress based on default value?

Tags: cypress

Below is a `select` control in my app:

```html
<select id="answer">
    <option value="yes"> Yes <option>
    <option value="no"> No <option>
    <option value="maybe"> Maybe <option>
</select>
```

One of the above values will always be selected by default when the page loads.

A problem I have is that I won't know what that default value will be each time.

Here is an example of the Cypress test I'm trying to write:

```
Given the select control is visible
When I select a different option
Then the selected option is updated
```

Here's what I am trying to do in pseudo-code:

```js
cy.get('select').select(~~ any option that isn't the default value ~~)
```

Is it possible to write something like the above? I just want to update the selected option to something other than the default value (but I won't know that default value until during the test, as it will be random)

Example of how it would work during a test run:

- The page loads & the default selected option is 'No'
- Cypress should get the default selected value ('no')
- Then select an option that is not equal to 'no'
- Validate the selected option value is 'no'

Example of how the test might run a second time:

- The page loads & the default selected option is 'Maybe'
- Cypress should get the default selected value ('maybe')
- Then select an option that is not equal to 'maybe'
- Validate the selected option value is 'maybe'

Comment: How does your DOM look for the default selection?

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the value of the element on load, and use the `option` underneath the select to find one that does not equal the initial value.

```js
cy.get('select')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((val) => {
    cy.get('select').find('option').then(($options) => {
      const notSelected = $options.filter((x) => $options[x].value !== val);
      const ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * notSelected.length);
      cy.get('select').select(notSelected[ranNum].value);
    });
  });
```

Comment: It will work with `$options[x].value !== val`.

Comment: And `const ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * notSelected.length)`

Comment: Thanks, I was typing it out on my IDE and didn't copy over everything correctly. :D

Answer (score 1):

The random starting value is a bit of an anti-pattern for testing.

Maybe try to force the initial value to be the 1st, then cycle through the options.

```js
const options = ['yes', 'no', 'maybe']

function nextOption(current) {
  return (options.indexOf(current) + 1) % options.length
} 

function selectAnotherOption() {
  cy.get('select')
    .invoke('val')
    .then(current => {
      cy.get('select').select(nextOption(current))
    }) 
}

cy.get('select').select('Yes')
cy.get('select').should('have.value', 'yes')

selectAnotherOption()
cy.get('select').should('have.value', 'no')

selectAnotherOption()
cy.get('select').should('have.value', 'maybe')

selectAnotherOption()
cy.get('select').should('have.value', 'yes')
```

I had a crack at making the above test "blind" (starting from any random value) but frankly the test gets awfully complicated and it's hard to know if you're testing anything of value.